# Source control: Focus on previous / next view (i.e. up / down navigation of repositories)

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the Source Control view of a multi-root workspace, does VSCode provide any command IDs to navigate **up** / **down** the different repositories?

E.g. any way to associate a **keybinding** to **move up** / **down** in the list of repositories in the source control view?

[image]

Comment: Please check out `File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Git`

Comment: @csg . I did that already - What exactly are you suggesting I look for?